# Is their a way to make your java GUI (using Window Builder) possible to work with Graphics in eclipse?

Tags: java, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm trying to use 2D graphics and make it work with Window Builder in eclipse and i tried plenty of combinations of how to use it but I kept getting errors, it wouldnt let me run it because it would give me syntax errors or the thing wont even work.

I tried to make a method and tried to make the Rectangle shape but no use. I like to work this out but i'm not to sure how this will work out.

Example of the code would be,

This code would be the base.

```
package com.cookie.clicker;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GraphicsTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GraphicsTest window = new GraphicsTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GraphicsTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you manage to add a Rectangle on this!

Comment: what specific errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your class has to extend JFrame. In the future should use the wizards provided by WindowBuilder. Select your java package and then press CTRL+N. This will open the "New" wizard where you can select the WB JFrame class.

The getting started page is here:

https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/index.html